# QuerySelector arroja null

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema que cuando uso querySelector para llamar elementos dentro de un div en al ejecutar en consola me arroja "NULL" o directamente no muestra nada

Este es mi código javaScript

```
console.log("Esta línea se ejecuto antes de iniciar");

window.onload=function(){
    const divDetalles=document.querySelector("#principal");
    console.log(divDetalles);
    var divAux=divDetalles.document.querySelector("div.fondo_tabla");
    console.log(divAux);

};
```

Este es lo que me arroja si intento acceder un div que tiene dentro
[image: Este es lo que me arroja si intento acceder]Y este es el HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en lugar de `.onload` no deberias de validar que este `onready` la pagina?

Answer (score 2):

Sobra el valor **document** en la sentencia

```
var divAux=divDetalles.document.querySelector("div.fondo_tabla");
```

debería decir

```
var divAux=divDetalles.querySelector("div.fondo_tabla");
```

Comment: Creo que debes quitar el punto del `"div.fondo_tabla"` y cambiarlo por espacio: `"div #fondo_tabla"`. Auque no estoy muy seguro, antes no sabía que se podia hacer esto: `var divAux=divDetalles.querySelector("div #fondo_tabla");`

Comment: El # se utiliza para denotar ids. En este caso, **fondo_tabla** es una clase y por lo tanto se usa el punto

Comment: `querySelector` parece que usa la sintaxis de css para seleccionar objetos.

Comment: Ya lo corregí, gracias pero ahora me muestra que el div #pricipal está vacio, imprimo el segundo div y solo me arroja NULL

Comment: Imprimo div por div y el que tiene #principal me imprime que no tiene nada dentro

Comment: Efectivamente Daniel, son los mismos selectores, de ahí el nombre querySelector. Puedes ver la documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Juan, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que estás imprimiendo?